# How to handle an aggravating revision comment?

Tags: discussion, edits, edit-summary, be-nice-policy

When I ask a question on Stack Overflow, I'm trying to follow guidelines: being clear, show examples, format my text, use the appropriate tags. But I can sometimes make slight mistakes, which of course are picked by some users, who take some of their time to edit my post.

Nevertheless, the edit can come with an edit summary that can be perceived as quite aggressive, belittling, even aggravating. I looked for a way to respond in some way to such edit summaries only to find there is apparently no conventional way to do so. It can become quite frustrating when you don't completely agree with the revision itself.

So here is my question: is Stack Overflow really a place where moderators can freely aggravate users without consequences in exchange for their valuable time? Or is there *some* way to remind such users of Stack Overflow's model: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice?

Comment: Whatever it is, don't add this _Thanks for the **nearly insulting revision comment** by Neil Stockton._ in your question

Comment: I was frustrated, but quickly realized it would have been useless and irrelevant to the question that was asked, on top of prompting for unnecessary drama/digression. That's why i removed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ignore it.

You could @-comment the editor, but it's usually not worth it.

I think that the specific case is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44784138/revisions):

> No, this is NOT The JPA API. It is Hibernate API. Big difference. Dont people know what they are using?

That was a blunt edit summary, but I don't think it crosses the line. (Just to be clear here, I do **not** recommend such bluntness in edit summaries!)

Consider the first two sentences, check if the editor is correct, and then leave it be. The editor did not insult you personally, but rather observed that there is a lot of mis-tagging going on.

I know it feels bad, but I think we should assume that the editor really meant well. If they did, that's the best response. And if they did mean to insult, then ignoring the insult is still the best way to go about it.

Only if they really cross the line (for example, using Godwins) is action required - a flag on the post, asking for moderator intervention.

Comment: So in a nutshell, I shouldn't expect editors to be cordial, and grow a thicker skin? I guess I was taken by surprise by this kind of bluntness on a website that's promoting benevolent mutual learning.

Comment: @MichaëlVreux That would be the best. I've been taken aback by some of the responses I've gotten myself. But Stack Overflow is notoriously direct, so it's best to get used to it. Keep in mind that, despite the directness and the bluntness, these people are still trying to help. Sometimes Stack Overflow is like a grumpy old teacher who never seems to approve of what the kids do... but who will help them get their work done.

Comment: Since I came across this post I've changed the edit summary to read *not related to jpa api* @MichaëlVreux

Comment: I really do like the grumpy old teacher analogy: after all, i was always conscious that deep down, the intention of most people in the community is indeed good.

Comment: *That was a blunt edit summary* Usually mine involve accusing the OP of making me punch babies for various reasons (e.g., asking about a question but linking to an answer on the question...)

Comment: Well, maybe the OP didn't understand the answer he's linking to. It's really not constructive to go be blunt, even when the OP is a complete moron. Everyone's here to learn. And sometimes, the thing you'll learn is that your question was badly formulated or that it proves your own efforts to be insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If the revision comment is insulting/frustrating, you can always flag it (the post) for moderator's attention (and explain the situation / request editing out the insulting part).

No confrontation with the editor, the mods will probably edit, the insulting part is removed from history and all is well in the new alternate universe.

The editor may have had all the good intention in the world but he managed to frustrate you. Even if he changed his mind later, he couldn't edit or delete a revision comment. My rule of thumb is:

**If it insults or bothers you, flag it.**

Comment: It's easy to aggravate someone without even realizing it when you're bored and edit a number of posts a day as distraction, without even caring there are real human being behind every one of those questions. In my case, i was excited to see there might be a solution to my problem, only to see the only person who bothered answering was merely fixing a slight issue, and offered some belittling along with it.